# Join Two Select Queries having where clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT JIVE_USER_ID,
       EMAIL_ID, 
       USER_ID 
FROM VIK_USER WHERE EMAIL_ID='user@example.com';
```

#### Result is

```
JIVE_USER_ID    EMAIL_ID              USER_ID
11222            user@example.com     User
```

#### Another query is

```
SELECT  VIK_USER_PROFILE.FIRST_NAME,
        VIK_USER_PROFILE.LAST_NAME,
        VIK_USER.EMAIL_ID 
FROM VIK_USER,VIK_USER_PROFILE 
WHERE VIK_USER_PROFILE.USER_ID=VIK_USER.USER_ID;
```

#### Result is

```
FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME     EMAIL_ID
Ray            User        user@exmaple.com
```

I want to get  the result using a single block statement.How can I join these two select statements into one.

Thank You.

Comment: The answer is in your question. You need to `JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select VIK_USER.JIVE_USER_ID,
       VIK_USER.EMAIL_ID, 
       VIK_USER.USER_ID,
       VIK_USER_PROFILE.FIRST_NAME,
       VIK_USER_PROFILE.LAST_NAME,
       VIK_USER.EMAIL_ID
from VIK_USER, VIK_USER_PROFILE
where VIK_USER_PROFILE.USER_ID=VIK_USER.USER_ID
and VIK_USER.EMAIL_ID='user@example.com'
```

To elaborate, VIK_USER and VIK_USER_PROFILE are in an INNER JOIN (the comma is just a shortcut).

The join condition is `VIK_USER_PROFILE.USER_ID=VIK_USER.USER_ID`. JOINs have join conditions, usually on columns which share the same values across two tables.

Alternatively, the exact same query can be written as such:

```
select *
from VIK_USER
inner join VIK_USER_PROFILE on VIK_USER_PROFILE.USER_ID=VIK_USER.USER_ID
where VIK_USER.EMAIL_ID='user@example.com';
```

Comment: Thank you Jen..
I too got the same worka round for it..Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above joins the tables and filters based on where or and clause.
This may be inefficient for big tables.
Instead filter the table for particular id and then join.